# Laravel Timeout Error when sending an email

Tags: php, laravel, email, timeout, sendgrid

So here's the thing. I have to present the system I developed tomorrow, and there's a transaction where an email has to be sent. 

The problem is, there is no stable internet connection in the area where I'm going to be presenting.

Last time, I tried sending an email, it took some time (more or less a minute) before it showed me an error message. Something like "Timeout." I think it's because the internet is slow.

Now I can't recreate the error because I have a stable connection right now. 
Is there any way I could catch the error? Or prolong the session before it shows the timeout error?

 Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use chrome network throttling to simulate unstable connections
[https://css-tricks.com/throttling-the-network/](https://css-tricks.com/throttling-the-network/)

Comment: @AndréLuizdeGusmão or would it help to set the 'max_execution_time' longer than 30 secs?

Comment: Try both, one at a time.

Comment: @AndréLuizdeGusmão i tried network throttling. it's already been 1.8 mins since the request has been sent yet no error is showing.

Comment: @AndréLuizdeGusmão i just found a solution, I tried using Mail::failures()

Comment: Can you give more info about the code?
You are running your server on localhost right? You tagged your questions with sendgrid, maybe the problem is the server communication with sendgrid in a low bandwith context.
In that case you can host your app in [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel) for example, its free.